# PHP PDO Select query not selecting rows from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am running this PDO query:

```
$stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare("SELECT * from billing_control where sequence = :sequence ");
$stmt->execute(array(':sequence' => $_GET["sequence"]));
$result = $stmt->fetch();
```

to select rows from a database but when i do a var_dump($smtm); I get this result:

```
object(PDOStatement)#2 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(57) "SELECT * from billing_control where sequence = :sequence " }
```

I have `?sequence=178` on the end of my URL so it should be running the SQL:

```
select * from billing_control where sequence = 178
```

Any ideas what I have got wrong?

Comment: Are you connected to the db?

Comment: Did you check the value of, or if is defined $_GET["sequence"] ?

Comment: I believe that can't retrieve query string with parameters inserted using defaul PDO class, only if you make your own custom. You should check received query inside your DB. Also make sure you cast your parameters to correct type before you bind (or in bindParam method)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare("SELECT * from billing_control where sequence = :sequence ");
$stmt->bindParam(':sequence', $_GET["sequence"])
$stmt->execute();
```

Another version would be:

```
$stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare("SELECT * from billing_control where sequence = ? ");
$stmt->execute(array("%$_GET[sequence]%"));
```

Comment: the code i have put in my question works on other SELECT queries, is there any reason it wouldnt work?

Comment: Do those queries also include binding a variable to a GET parameter?

Comment: im not sure, the code in my question is the only code i have to select the row

Comment: I have just set $sequence = $_GET["sequence"]; and then $stmt->execute(array(':sequence' => $sequence));

Comment: do i need to create variables for everything ?

Comment: I'm not following you completely here, but you've got a working query now so it shouldn't be that hard to debug on your own. Perhaps this comment from PHP.net can shed some light on placeholders in PDO: http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.bindparam.php#99698

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query = $pdo_conn->prepare("SELECT * from billing_control where sequence = :sequence ");
$query->bindParam(':sequence', $_GET["sequence"], PDO::PARAM_STR, 255); //I assume that sequence data is string
$result = $query->execute();
```